# c# Using SslStream.WriteAsync at high speeds

Tags: sslstream

i am facing an annoying problem with SslStream.WriteAsync

here is the code

```
public void Send(PacketWriter writer)
{
    var buffer = writer.GetWorkspace();

    _sslStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
}
```

When writing the data at extremely high speed it tells me

`The beginwrite method cannot be called when another write operation is pending`

[NOTE] : I mean by high speed something like this

```
for (var i = 0 ; i <= 1000; i++)
{
    Send(somedata);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must wait until the previous asynchronous write has finished.

Change your send method to return a `Task`:

```
public Task Send(PacketWriter writer)
{
    var buffer = writer.GetWorkspace();
    return _sslStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
}
```

Make the calling method `async`, then await until each send operation completes:

```
for (var i = 0 ; i <= 1000; i++)
{
    await Send(somedata);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be try this-

```
 private static void send_data(SslStream socket_stream, byte[] data)
        {
          Task task = new Task(() => { socket_stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length); });
          task.RunSynchronously();
          task.Wait();
        }
```

This will make sure all the messaages are sent in oderly manner without any exception